# Unicode to char* c++ 11

Tags: string, c++11, unicode, char

I want to know if is there any way to convert a unicode code to a string or char in C++ 11.
I've been trying with extended latin unicode letter Á (as an example) which has this codification:

letter: Á
Unicode: 0x00C1
UTF8 literal: \xc3\x81

I've been able to do so if it's hardcoded as:

```
const char* c = u8"\u00C1";
```

But if i got the byte sequence as a short, how can I do the equivalent to get the char* or std::string 'Á'?

EDIT, SOLUTION:

I was finally able to do so, here is the solution if anyone needs it:

```
std::wstring ws;
for(short input : inputList)
{
    wchar_t wc(input);
    ws += wc;
}
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> cv;
str = cv.to_bytes(ws);
```

Thanks for the comments they were very helpful.

Comment: use [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert)

Comment: I've used wchar_t to load the unicode bytes, and wstring to concat them, but I still have the problem of retrieving a normal char* or an std::string from it, any ideas?

Comment: if you use [`std::wstring_convert::to_bytes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/to_bytes) this is trivial

Comment: pro tip: just use `auto`

Answer (score 3):

The C++11 standard contains `codecvt_utf8`, which converts between some internal character type (try `char16_t` if your compiler has it, otherwise `wchar_t`) and UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I know that with wchar_t I'm able to retrieve it, but I still need the conversion to char* or std::string. Thanks for the reply anyways

Answer (score 1):

The problems is that `char` is only one byte length, while unicode characters require a size of two bytes.

You can still treat it as char*, but you must remember that you are not dealing with an ascii string (there will be zeros).

You may have to switch to `wchar_t`.